# Is forcing the order/placement of a #include bad practice?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I have a bit of code ("core.h" below) that is used with a few different wrappers. Each of the wrappers require it to have a differently sized array. Currently I am using a `#define` in the wrapper header file to specify the size of that array, but that `#define` must be written in the file before the header is included.

```
/*wrapper1.h*/
#define ARR_SIZE 42 // this must be written before-
#include "core.h"   // this to ensure correct operation
//...

/*wrapper2.h*/
#define ARR_SIZE 128
#include "core.h"
//...

/*core.h*/
#ifndef ARR_SIZE
#define ARR_SIZE 256 // default value
#endif
struct foo
{
   char arr[ARR_SIZE];
   //...
};
//...
```

Is this bad practice? If so, is there a nicer option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wrapper1.h and wrapper2.h are used in the same program (i.e. if you have a source file that `#include`s wrapper1.h and another that `#include`s wrapper2.h, then you can't use those two source files in the same project without considerable care to avoid problems - and most people doing this sort of thing are not that careful).    Doing so will violate the one definition rule (since `struct foo` will have more than one definition in your program).   That causes undefined behaviour according to the C standard.

If you use the wrapper#.h in different projects, there is no problem.   However, this is a mistake waiting to happen - for example, what is to stop you using wrapper1.h and wrapper2.h in the same project at some future time?   Nothing, that's what.   The result will be problems in your program (in worst case, intermittent runtime errors) that can be VERY hard to track down.

The question you need to ask is why you need to have different sizes in different wrappers, and what the real differences are.   Then design your headers (and functions affected by those headers) properly.   There is a point where code (header file in this case) reuse can cause more problems than it is worse, and this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I would encourage to not do it if possible. I've seen libs doing it that way and have had a headache by trying to find what's wrong.

A few rules from MISRA encourages you to not do it. Rule 3-1-1 for example.